# Tried 3 things to make Chrome accept remote self-signed SSL cert

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, chrome

I have a sandbox `Windows 2016` server in the cloud that only I use for dev, testing, and experimentation. I can access the site remotely from Chrome, but no matter what I try, Chrome displays the ominous SSL cert warning:

[image]

Relevant facts:

1. I created a hosts file entry that routes `configurator.local.com` to the IP of my MS cloud server. I can access it successfully (except for the ominous security warning), and I can also crash through that warning and view the site successfully.
2. I created a self-signed cert on the server for `configurator.local.com`. It works fine when running Chrome *on the server* (from inside an RDP session) with no cert warnings. There is also a hosts file entry for `configurator.local.com` on the server.

And here are the attempted solutions I have tried, but didn't make that cert warning go away:

1. I added this startup flag to Chrome: `--ignore-certificate-errors`
2. I downloaded the "not secure" cert through the client's browser (on my PC) and installed it into my `Trusted Root Certificates`.
3. I typed the `thisisunsafe` [cert warning override](https://dev.to/moshe/a-secret-way-to-bypass-chrome-s-security-privacy-error-4h6i) on the warning page.

Nothing works. This server is used by 1 person on earth: ME. So I really should be able to override this somehow and make that cert warning go away. Even though I can bypass the warning and get to the site, the ominous and omnipresent **Not secure** warning is always there to the left of the address bar.

What haven't I tried yet that might work?

Comment: The error message says that the name in the certificate does not match the name in the URL. It is unclear what exactly your certificate contains, specifically if the name is included as subject alternative names and not as CN. In any case it is not a good idea to use a public domain name which very likely does not belong to you for your own purpose. This can cause all kinds of strange problems, so better use reserved non-public TLD like .local for this purpose.

Comment: use LetsEncrypt?